# Работа с массивами, нахождение среднего арифметического по колонкам

Tags: c#

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter n:");
        int n=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter m:");
        int m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int [,]arr=new int [n, m];
        Random ran = new Random();
        int sum = 0;
        float middle = 0;

        for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
            {
                arr[i, j] = ran.Next(0, 100);


                    sum += arr[i, j];

                 middle = sum /( m*n);

                Console.Write(arr[i, j] + "\t");


            }
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
        Console.WriteLine("middle=" + middle);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

В двумерном массиве найти среднее арифметическое первой колонки и количество элементов в каждой из следующих колонок, превышающих среднее арифметическое предварительной колонки.
Смогла найти только среднее арифметическое всего массива

Comment: Что именно у Вас не получается?

Comment: Посчитать среднее арифметическое отдельных колонок, а не целого массива

Comment: array[i][колонка], где i - счетчик, колонка - номер столбца.

Comment: @Helpless, добавил в ответ то, что у Вас не получается

Comment: @Ares, благодарю)

Answer (score 0):

Я могу написать на С++.

```
for(int i = 0;i < n;++i){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int j = 0;j < m;++j){
        sum = sum + array[j][i];
    }
    int avr = sum / n;
    cout << avr << endl;
}
```

Как и человек попросил переведу С# хотя я в нем ни-ни

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter n:");
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter m:");
int m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int [,]arr=new int [n, m];
int []sum=new int [m];
Random ran = new Random();

for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
    {
        arr[i, j] = ran.Next(0, 100);

        Console.Write(arr[i, j] + "\t");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        sum[i] += arr[j, i];
    }
}

for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
{
    Console.Write(float(sum[i] / n)  + " ");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Мы фиксируем колону и проходим по всем строкам колоны.
Найдя сумму каждой колонки можно найти и средне арифметическую

Comment: В вопросе написано "на си шарп". Отвечать на поставленный вопрос, а не на какой-то другой.

Answer (score -1):

**Находим среднее арифметическое по колонкам:**

Пишем extension-метод:

```
public static class ArrExt
{
    public static double GetAverageForColumn(this int[,] arr, int i) =>
        Enumerable.Range(0, arr.GetLength(0)).Select(j => arr[j, i]).Average();
}
```

Используем (нумерация колонок начинается с 0):

```
var array = new int[,]
{
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 1, 12, 5 },
    { 1, 5, 3 }
};

var average = array.GetAverageForColumn(1);
Console.WriteLine(average);
```